# Warn users refreshing page but allow url change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which will warn the user if they refresh the page which works well.

However when a user clicks a button or something that may just be href='#' or even a url change by my website, they are also warned. How can I only show this alert when they try to refresh the browser?

Thanks

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'WARNING: You are about to reload this page, doing so will loose all your open tabs and loose any unsaved data.';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'WARNING: You are about to reload this page, doing so will loose all your open tabs and loose any unsaved data.';
};
```

Comment: Spelling fix: `lose` not `loose` :)

Comment: lol thanks - that would of been embarrassing :)

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but I wouldn't write *would of been*, either. ;-)

Comment: the only way I see this working is to have a global variable that will actually be set to TRUE if anything is changed and not saved on page and then set to FALSE when a save occurs - that way you'll know when the dialog definitely should appear to the visitor

Comment: in any case, assigning a function to `window.onbeforeunload` is discouraged (since it can overwrite other functions assigned to same beforeunload function)... [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and `attachEvent` handlers are a better alternative ;-)

Comment: @DavidFregoli my comment was meant globally as a coding practise, it's not meant to be specifically tight to onbeforeunload

Comment: @Zathrus yes but with onbeforeunload overwriting the function is often the desired behaviour `ie: window.onbeforeunload = $.noop` when all the changes have been saved

Comment: @DavidFregoli you're probably right, I'll leave this conversation here, so others can learn from it (just as I did now :P)

Comment: @ZathrusWriter on the other hand I just found out that you can actually attach more events to it with `addEventListener`, as long as they don't retrun anything (or return undefined).

Comment: @DavidFregoli interesting concept, so you can handle multiple areas of page that needs checking for changes by using multiple event handlers... nice :)

Answer (score 2):

concept solution (in jQuery):

```
var going_away = true;
$("a").click(function()
{
// if it's local link - $(this).attr('href').indexOf("#") == 0 || $(this).attr('href').indexOf("/") == 0
   going_away = false;
});

$("form").submit(function()
{
// if it's local action - $(this).attr('action').indexOf("/") == 0
   going_away = false;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
   if (going_away)
       window.confirm(...)
}
```

EDIT: of course the premise of the conditions is to target outgoing links, thus probably we should check for http, or some other way that distinguishes local from outgoing links.

Comment: Excellent, sounds like a great idea! Thanks :)

Comment: please be aware that this does not account for JS redirects via onClick handlers from elements other than anchors and forms via the following syntax: `window.location.href = 'page.html'` or for META redirects

Comment: Although a good solution, you are only capturing certain navigation actions. What about when the user navigates away from the page by typing in the URL, or using back, or forward?

Comment: @Buchow_PHP in those situations the onbeforeupload event should fire (actually, you've got me thinking, and I'm not sure anymore :D). Unfortunately, as it's not possible to have access to the history object (in terms of - what user visited afterwards, or beforehand arriving on given page) doing this purely in JS is (I think) impossible.

Comment: Tested under FF for the back and forward buttons, and yes, clicking them does fire onbeforeunload (why did I doubt that it doesn't :D). Although I found that for the back button we can access the `document.referrer` (for non `history` manipulated pages, this should be the previous page?)

Comment: @eithed what I meant by "you are only capturing certain navigation actions" was that only anchor clicks and form submission events would result in going_away being set as false. The user only wants the alert on refresh, but, as you mentioned, back and forward will fire the onbeforeupload with going_away == true, which will alert the user.

Comment: Yes I realize this now too, I tried the solution but I also have other JS files which call external links so not it does not work for my purpose! I will have to look into it further :(